# AngularJS issues when using it with Symfony3 form: it doesn't display old values if the form submitted with errors

Tags: angularjs, forms, validation, twig, symfony

When I use AngularJS with a symfony form, with constraint validation. Then if I submit my form with invalid data, the system redirect me to the form with error messages, but all the inputs are empty, so the user can't see the invalid values that he entered.

Apparently, this error is caused by AngularJS because he initiate the models.

What can I do to solve this problem?

Comment: Please post your code in question. Thank you!

Comment: thank you i solved the problem by doing this : 

 `ng-init="prenom = '{{ form.prenom.vars.value }}'"`

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I solved the problem by doing this : `ng-init="prenom = '{{ form.prenom.vars.value }}'"`.